# Why do values differ when converting from Array to Float32Array?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I've noticed differences in values when converting from an `Array` to a `Float32Array`, as in this example:

```
var aPoints = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) { 
      aPoints.push(Math.random())
}

console.log('aPoints array', aPoints);

aPointsF = new Float32Array(aPoints);

for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    console.log(Math.abs(aPoints[i] - aPointsF[i]));
}
```

I'd expected the differences to be zero, but the loop does show differences, however tiny.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should never compare floating-point values, (in any language, it's not js specific issue) and if you have to you need to check for sth like this
`Math.abs(a-b)<very_small_value`.

When you operate in any way on floating point numbers result can't be exact because precision is finite, so result needs to rounded somehow and by rounded I mean binary representation not the decimal one.

In this particular case you are converting `Number`(most likely float64) type to float32, so if you are writing `0.1234567` to `aPoints` that value after conversion might be `0.1234`. Those 2 values are just to illustrate what is happening, in reality it wouldn't just cut last few decimal points because rounding I'm talking about are happening on binary representation.

You can read more about how floating point numbers are represent in binary here http://cstl-csm.semo.edu/xzhang/Class%20Folder/CS280/Workbook_HTML/FLOATING_tut.htm